# How can i make my css background smaller

Tags: html, css

Does anyone know how to do this?
links:

http://prntscr.com/ehb1bl
 http://prntscr.com/ehaywl

How can i cut the background from those marks?
Background-size is not working.

Comment: Try giving class="skin" a specific width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a{
margin-left: Number px;
margin-right: Number px;
}
```

Setting your margins should do it. You can also use a percentage instead of px for scaling. Hope this helps